# initActivity Postmonger event not fired

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

My goals is to create a custom activty for JourneyBuilder.

At this point, I am able to create one, which can send EXECUTE requests to an external app. 
Now I want to add some customization during activity's configuration phase (e.g. add a text for a messaging activity). I followed this demo app tutorial:

https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node

where they pushed the configuration message into *inArguments* array of the activity's JSON. This happens after *initActivity* event is captured.

**And here comes my problem. It seems, that neither *initActivity* nor *initActivityRunningModal* is ever fired during the process of configuration (*ready* event is being triggered.)** Veryfied through console.log().

Moreover, when I switched back to the official example of a custom activity:
(https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/extend/example-rest-activity.html) I found, that I also can't capture events like *clickedNext* and event *updateButton* sent to the JB has no visible effect at all.

The connection should be OK since I can detect *getEndpoins* and *requestPayload* events being triggered.

What may I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my fault. 
After adding some logs into Postmonger library I've noticed that I recieve completely different events, than expected. After searching here on StackExchange I've found, that I was using old version of API (this post helped o lot: [updateActivity method with Journey Builder Customer Activities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48981/updateactivity-method-with-journey-builder-customer-activities/50624)). 
So, the only thing needed to make it work is to add/change a line `"workflowApiVersion": "1.1"` into *config.json*